# High memory usage with laravel queue

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I'm using laravel queue to perform background tasks.

After starting the queue (either with "php artisan queue:work" or with supervisor), htop indicates a memory usage of ~2GB for the process - even with no jobs in the queue.

Here's the result of "sudo systemctl status supervisor" (numprocs = 1) :

```
supervisor.service - Supervisor process control system for UNIX
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/supervisor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-06-23 11:39:35 CEST; 7s ago
       Docs: http://supervisord.org
   Main PID: 2850495 (supervisord)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 618982)
     Memory: 1.9G
        CPU: 2.574s
     CGroup: /system.slice/supervisor.service
             ├─2850495 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
             └─2850496 php /var/www/html/pharavel/artisan queue:work --max-time=10800 --timeout=20 --tries=1
```

I doesnt seem to increase while processing jobs so I guess I can exclude a memory leak.

Laravel queue documentation states that :

> queue workers are long-lived processes and store the booted application state in memory

However I'm not sure how it can consume so much memory.

EDIT : The worker configuration for the supervisor :

```
[program:pharavel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/pharavel/artisan queue:work --max-time=10800 --timeout=10 --tries=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
;user=forge
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/pharavel/storage/logs/pharavel-worker.log
stopwaitsecs=7200
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling with a similar problem, my laravel queue worker uses 1.5GB RAM after processing some jobs, and never seem to reclaim any memory even when idle.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't investigate further. The same configuration resulted in much more reasonable memory usage on the production server, so we didn't feel the need to delve deeper.

Comment: Haha, I see. I'm having the opposite problem, I can't reproduce it locally but it explodes in production. Hard to pinpoint the cause without a reproduction case locally.

Answer (score 0):

Queue worker keeps pooling, it ruuns as a daemon. If you are using cron do not run queue workers with it since it spins up a worker every defined time
Instead be sure to use supervisor. See [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment) from laravel official docs:

Queue:COMMAND will instruct all queue workers to gracefully "die" after they finish processing their current job so that no existing jobs are lost. Since the queue workers will die when the queue:restart command is executed, you should be running a process manager such as Supervisor to automatically restart the queue workers.

As suggested use Supervisor to manage queues (more details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#supervisor-configuration))

Comment: We use supervisor on the server. The memory usage is 2GB per child process.

Comment: are you saying each Supervisor process takes 2 gb ?

Comment: The supervisor main process takes 20MB. Each subprocess takes 2GB indeed.

Comment: would you mind to share /etc/supervisor/conf.d and any .conf files related to workers (if created)

Comment: I edited the question with the supervisor config. I dont think they are other configs related to workers

Comment: thanks, big question lets say memory is maxing out. can you manually run php artisan queue:restart What happens with the memory ?

Comment: I tried that -wondering if the high memory usage was related to the supervisor. But it takes the exact same amount of memory (2GB). It looks like the process itself of storing the app in memory requires the 2GB.